# How to have different rule for a specific collection in firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have  a firestore db, for all collections I want to have below rule

```
    allow read : if request.auth.uid != null ;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid != null ;
```

except for `service-account` collection, which I don't want anybody has access (only firebase functions since they are running under admin service account) so I updated my rules to

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
        allow read : if request.auth.uid != null ;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null ;
    }

    match /service-account/{serviceAccount} {
      allow read: if false;
      allow write:  if false;
    }

  }
}
```

Then I tried to test it via `Rules Play Ground`, rules are teken into account but result is not correct

[image]

So my rule correctly ban access, but the first rule which is going to be applied for all, seems to allow read. I changed the order and no diffrenece.

How can I fix this.

Comment: If you have multiple `match` statements, they are OR'ed together. But you can capture the condition in a single `match` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74973108/209103

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this rule is unconditionally applied to every single document in your database:

```
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read : if request.auth.uid != null ;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null ;
    }
```

With this in place, all documents are readable and writable by all users.  You cannot override this with another rule.  Once a document is deemed readable by any rule, that can't be changed.

See the documentation for [overlapping match statements](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements).

What you will need to do instead is call out each individual collection by its name (except service-account), and apply the permissions to them individually.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, the problem is I have around 50 other collections, so naming them one by one would be a pain ;(

Comment: Yes, sounds like it.  You don't have any alternatives, however, without restructuring things to be nested under some top-level collection that you can recursively apply rules to.