# firebase firestore rules authenticated access to all collections except one

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following firestore structure, basically 3 collections

publicdata
protecteddata1
protecteddata2

I want to have protecteddata1 and protecteddata 2, and really the entire firestore database as authenticated users only. 
But i want the public to have readonly access to 'publicdata' collection..

The following is my attempt but it doesn't work

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if (request.auth.uid != null);
    }
    match /publicdata {
       allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The best answer is currently one of the least-upvoted below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74973108/807126

Comment: Lengend himself is answering . How can it be wrong!!

Comment: This one might help you https://www.aravi.me/blog/firebase-cloud-firestore-security-rules/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following functions I created to do this

```
function isUserAuthenticated() {
    return request.auth.uid != null; 
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isUserAuthenticated();
    }
    
    match /publicdata/{itemId} {
      allow read : if true;
      allow create : if isUserAuthenticated();
      allow update: if isUserAuthenticated();
      allow delete: if isUserAuthenticated();
    }

    /* Functions */
    function isUserAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth.uid != null; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: was getting a null error - but changing the function fixes it: 
    function isUserAuthenticated() {      
      return request.auth != null; 
    }

Comment: Glad my answer helped you :)

Answer (score 8):

As others have explained, if you have multiple matches for the same document they are OR'ed together, so you can't implement an exception with that.

What you can do though is capture the collection name in a variable, and then implement the exception in a single match:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{collection}/{document=**} {
      allow read: if collection != 'publicdata';
      allow write: if (request.auth.uid != null);
    }
  }
}
```

So here we allow reads from all collections except `publicdata`.

Answer (score 1):

Because [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements) is says:

> ### Overlapping match statements
>
> It's possible for a document to match more than one match statement. In the case where multiple allow
> expressions match a request, the access is allowed if any of the
> conditions is true: ...

You can use this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  // Check if the request is authenticated
  function isAuthenticated() {
    return request.auth != null;
  }

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if isAuthenticated();
    }
    match /publicdata/{document=**} {
        allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```