# Restrict only one collection from writing in Firestore Database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have several collections in `Firestore` and I want to prevent writing ONLY to '`products`' collection.

I tried this script but it does not work:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /products/{id} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you capture the collection name in a variable, you can test for that in your condition. I just added an answer to show how to do that to the duplicate that Doug linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74973108/209103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this

#### Preferred

1. According to  [Frank van Puffelen](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/74973108/13431819)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{collection}/{document=**} {
      allow read: if (request.auth.uid != null);
      allow write: if collection != 'products'; 
      //  This will allow write permission to all collection except products collection.
    }
  }
}
```

#### Trivial way

2. As [@Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson) suggested in the comment and in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60974541/13431819).

- Firestore security rules implement an `allowlist` and not a `denylist`.
- So you'll have to specify rules to every other `collection`.
- Only for the `products` collection deny the `write` permission

  ```
  service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

      match /orders/{order} {   
        allow read, write,update,delete: if request.auth != null; // Give permission to orders document
      }

      match /carts/{cart} {
        allow read, write,update,delete: if request.auth != null; //  Give permission to carts document
      }

      match /products/{product} {
        allow read : if request.auth != null; //  Here dont give  permission to write
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The OP wants to make all collections writable except one.  You have it the other way around.

Comment: I have given justice to the answer  including  the better way giving credits to @Frank and you  . Thank you for letting me know the error in my answer