# How to match Rest of Collections in firestore rules?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have like 50+ collections on firestore and now I am working on security rules.
let's say all collections should have the same rules like (read and write if user is autheticated).
and only one collection has some different criteria.

I used the following:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /LovesCollection/{loveid} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/UsersCollection/$(request.auth.uid)).data.User_admin_type == Owner;
    }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

the result here is that the second match overrides the first one and the user have write access if only authenticated.

so I am wondering if there is a way to say "rest of collections" or I have to go for all collections one by one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have different rule for a specific collection in firebase firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893855/how-to-have-different-rule-for-a-specific-collection-in-firebase-firestore)

Comment: Thanks, I had to specifiy each collection in the rules, it worked after all.